# How to convert array in python to be compliant with Google Charts while returning in AJAX

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data in the database in the following format, this is only part of the data ( first row is for columns )

```
('Week Number', 'Building', 'Path', 'Scenario, 'Value' ),
(1, 'A', 1, 'Scen1', 312),
(1, 'B', 2, 'Scen2', 123),
(1, 'C', 3, 'Scen3', 34324),
(2, 'A', 1, 'Scen1', 123),
(2, 'B', 2, 'Scen2', 431),
(2, 'C', 3, 'Scen3', 555)
```

And I have no idea how to convert this to a format required by Google Chart format.

I would need to somehow have this converted and returned in the following format (as an array)

```
['Week Number', 'A - Scen1', 'B - Scen2', 'C - Scen3'],
['1',  312,  123, 34324], # first line of the above result from database  
['2',  123, 431, 555],
['3',  660,  1120, 1320],
['4',  1030, 540, 440]
.......
```

As you can see, scenario and building are combined and the values in line with weekends

I've no idea how to do that, was trying to do something:

```
for path in result:

    newPath = False
    if not path in data: newPath = True
    if newPath: data[ path ] = ['Week Number']

    for label in result[path]:
        for week_number in result[path][label]:
            value = result[path][label][week_number]
```

But it doesn't bring added value.

Will be very thankful for the help

Comment: How do you get those data? Are they strings or tuples?

Comment: this is in my private database, I've pasted it here https://pastecode.xyz/view/613e50a7

Comment: Are they stored in a plain text file?

Comment: yes, here is the file - https://www73.zippyshare.com/v/wndfz1sY/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample data you provided in your question, here is how you can do it:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('data.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    lines = [literal_eval(elem) for elem in inFile.read().split(',\n')]
    weekNumbers = sorted(set(line[0] for line in lines))
    result = []
    for weekNumber in weekNumbers:
        tempList = []
        tempList.append(weekNumber)
        for line in lines:
            if line[0]==weekNumber:
                tempList.append(line[-1])
        result.append(tempList)

    for elem in result:
        print(elem)
```

Sample data:

```
(1, 'A', 1, 'Scen1', 312),
(1, 'B', 2, 'Scen2', 123),
(1, 'C', 3, 'Scen3', 34324),
(2, 'A', 1, 'Scen1', 123),
(2, 'B', 2, 'Scen2', 431),
(2, 'C', 3, 'Scen3', 555)
```

Result:

```
[1, 312, 123, 34324]
[2, 123, 431, 555]
```

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I need, thank you! Is there also a chance to add, as a first element in array, the labels ? which is Week number as first value and scenarios after

Comment: You can add `result.append(['Week Number', 'A - Scen1', 'B - Scen2', 'C - Scen3'])` right before the loop. Glad I could help. Feel free to upvote or accept as answer if it helped and report any issue you may face.